# Electronjs Mysql database submit query random access

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, electron

I have some trouble issues with mysql interaction.

I have a form. When I try to click/submit and then call my function tata() to do some stuff with the database (select or whatever), the connection.query is call randomly. Sometimes when I click the function call for the first time and sometimes I need to click 2 or 3 times on the button to call the function. I have no logs warning or error. The function stop before connection.query but I don't know why because I just need to retry (re-click).

Example first click:

```
"Click myBtn"

alert('14.1')
alert('13')
```

Then finished.

If I stay in the same page but I click another time ->

```
alert('14.1')
alert('13')
alert('14.2')
```

I work on ubuntu 20.

My main.js :

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, netLog, contentTracing, session } = require('electron')

function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    title: "Ulrich The Keeper",
    icon: './src/webapp/public/assets/img/menu_icon.png',
    webPreferences: {
      //set to true to have internal nodejs function integration
      nodeIntegration: true,
      //enable remote module for the render script
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      //disable dev tools set to false in PROD
      devTools: true


    }
  }
)
  win.loadFile('index.html');

}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})
app.on('activate', () => {
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

my package.json

```
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "install-app-deps",
    "start": "electron . --no-sandbox"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "decache": "^4.6.0",
    "electron": "^10.1.4",
    "electron-builder": "^22.9.1"
      },
  "dependencies": {
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"

  }
}
```

my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ulrich The Keeper</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/login_style.css">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="login-dark">
        <form id="myForm_index" method="POST">
            <h2 class="sr-only">Login Form</h2>
            <div class="illustration"><i class="icon ion-ios-locked-outline"></i></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input id=form_index_login class="form-control" type="text" name="login" placeholder="Login" required></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input id=form_index_password class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" aria-describedby="PasswordHelp" required></div>
            <small id="PasswordHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter your credentials to unlock your vault </small>

            <div class="form-group">
              <button id=myBtn class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" >Log In</button>
            </div>
            <a href="register.html" class="forgot">Click here to register</a>

        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- Placing scripts at the bottom of the <body> element improves the display speed, because script interpretation slows down the display. -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<script>
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", tata);

function tata(){
  var mysql = require("mysql");
  var db_config = require('../../../server/database_config.js');

  var host = db_config.db_host;
  var user = db_config.db_user;
  var password = db_config.db_password;
  var name_database = db_config.db_name;

  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: host,
    user: user,
    password: password,
    database: name_database
  });
  alert('14.1')
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM `users`', function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw console.log(error);
    alert('14.2');
  });
  alert('13')
  connection.end();

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: connection.query('SELECT * FROM `users`', function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw console.log(error);
    connection.end();
  });
try moving the connection.end() call to inside the callback

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution.

I moved "type=submit" to "type=button" and it's works !

I don't know why exactly but it's works.

If you have any explanation, feel free !

```
<div class="form-group">
              <button id=myBtn class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="button" >Log In</button>
            </div>
```